Symmetry group and dualities
Let's say two quantum models $M_1$ and $M_2$ are dual to each other and let their symmetry groups be $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively. Is it necessary for $S_1$ to be isomorphic to $S_2$? (I thought so because models are dual.)
Note: models that I had in mind were dimerized XXZ chain and quantum Ashkin-Teller model (which are related via Krammers Wannier kind of duality transformation).

Please define "duality".  Symmetry group and isomorphism retains their strict mathematical meanings, but duality has been used in a much looser sense in physics.  In its proper sense, yes the symmetry group must be the same, because we just have the exact same system described in two different ways.

@T.P.Ho By duality I meant, mapping one model to some other model via some duality transform.

On second thought, actually I want to change my answer to no.  Even (or especially!) those mathematically rigorous duality maps in physics turn symmetry conserved current into topological current.  In other words, a symmetry transformation on one side has no counter part at all on the other.  Since the symmetries are completely different, there is a priori no reason for the groups to be isomorphic.
